# Did the Old Ones create Chaos to win the war with the C'tan?

Tags: warhammer-40k, necrons

I know that the canon around the start of the 40K universe has changed from edition to edition of 40K but I am sure that at one point the history was retconed so that it was the Old Ones who brought about the creation of the chaos gods because the only thing that could defeat the C'tan and Necrons was the power of the warp?

Reading the most recent history this does not seem to be the case but I know that Games Workshop has form in changing its history to fit the current line of products.

Am I right in thinking that, at least in one timeline, the Old Ones enabled the creation of the chaos gods as a side effect of using the warp to fight the war in Heaven?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as i am aware this is not the case, The old ones INDIRECTLY created the chaos gods in modern GW cannon when the old ones creations (Eldar, Slaan, Etc...) all felt intense emotions, died en-mass & used psychic powers during the war in heaven. This was the way that Khorne, Nurgle and Then Tzeench were made. Slaanesh, of course, came later. I can understand the confusion though since the reason those creations were made was to beat the Necrons with psychic powers. (In very old lore it's stated that human emotions created all of the Chaos gods during the medieval era, but that is just super-stupid so has since been ret-conned).

We know that the C'tan and the Necrons where eventually defeated primarily through infighting, It seems unlikely this would be the case if the chaos goods where in play.

That being said GW does do a lot of ret-cons and it's possible that in some piece of media it's stated that the old-one's made the chaos gods deliberately.

Comment: Necrons and C'tan weren't defeated: At the end of the War in Heavens Necrons turned on their C'tan overlords and defeated them, then they decided to fall asleep until they can regain biological bodies.

Comment: @Yasskier wasn't it more because the flesh species died en masse due to something the necrons couldn't battle? (demons / enslavers) and thus they decided to "sit/sleep it out"?

Comment: @Thomas I was bit imprecise: Old Ones were killed and young races were plagued by the warp creatures like Enslavers, while Necrons were weakened (but not defeated!) by their fight with C'tan. So instead of fighting the warp creatures and the rising power of Eldar, they've decided to take a nap until things will quiet down and a new, easier to dominate races will arise, so Necrons will be able to take over their bodies.

Comment: I think I may have got confused there in my head, although GW has rewritten the old ones history a myriad of different ways especially since the necrons where first released and they decided to change the history all around :).

Comment: @Yasskier this is what i meant by infighting, it's likely had the necrons & c'tan not fought they could have defeated the eldar then and there.

Comment: @Richard C I don't think that's going to change any time soon unless GW do a full on oldones release, they'd prefer to keep people guessing and keep theories circulating. Similar to the missing primarchs